# I want to schedule a .net task on my EC2 instance

Tags: .net, amazon-ec2, aws-lambda, scheduled-tasks, amazon-cloudwatch

Is there a way I can schedule a recurring job\task (a .net piece of code) that can run on my EC2 instance. (Ec2 that constantly running - I need to schedule a task that download some files to the Machine EBS).
some kind of AWS lambda function, that running on a specific machine. 
I want to use the abilities of Cloud-watch (or other component of AWS) to send the trigger, and to writing a controller\listener on side of the script.
is that possible?

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can schedule a task on EC2 through various means:

- Traditional Crontabs
- AWS CodeBuilds

With regards to lambda triggers through cloud-watch you can use the source as cloudwatch logs or cloudwatch event bridge while defining the lambda trigger. And the best part is your lambda can be a .Net App 3.1(C#/Powershell) or 2.1(C#/Powershell).

**Cheers and happy coding!**

Comment: can you explain more about aws codebuilds and Traditional Crontabs

Comment: so the design you mean to point the cloudwatch/bridge to trigger a code in c# that creats cron and send it to aws Code builds?